# refresh a canvas to draw a new object

Tags: jogl

Hello everybody i'm new here and new on the opengl and 3d world i have successfuly load and display an obj file but whene i reload a new one by pressing a jbutton the new one is drawn under the old one please can you help me to refresh the glcanvas.

Comment: Are you using an Animator? Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say what your jbutton does so im guessing you are reinitializing your drawable when you load your new object.. In my experience this only adds a new drawable to your canvas.. I would prefer to just change whats beeing drawn but if not heres how to close your current drawable/canvas:

```
        try {
            canvas.getContext().makeCurrent();
            canvas.getContext().release();
            canvas.getContext().destroy();
            drawable.getContext().makeCurrent();
            drawable.getContext().release();
            drawable.getContext().destroy();

        } catch (GLException releaseFailure) {
            releaseFailure.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then reinitialize them when you add the new object..

Comment: i'im working on a facial animation application using jogl and obj wavefront files i loaded and displayed a 3D face and thanks to your answer i solved the problem now it works very well when i load a face with a simple clic at a JButton but when i use a JFilechooser to choose a face it does not appear unless i resize manually the frame here is the code i use

Comment: open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve){            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();          chooser.setDialogTitle("choose a model");                         int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);                          if( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {                    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();                         name=f.getName(); }                                    makeContentCurrent();canvas.requestFocus();loadmodel();canvas.setVisible(true); context.release(); } });

Comment: i just want to say thank you so much for your help i foind the solutio, to the last probleme i just needed tp put canvas.repaint(); here is the code

Comment: open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve){
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogTitle("choose a model");
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
try {
name=f.getCanonicalPath();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
file=f.getParent();
}

makeContentCurrent();
canvas.requestFocus();                        loadobj();
canvas.repaint();
context.release();
}});